# Font Consolas in Pycharm is being rendered in a weird way

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

On the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GQYJ.png) below Consolas 10pt in Font Manager and in Pycharm 2.7.2
In Pycharm it became small and bold-ish
Is there a way to render it similar to Windows style?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a problem with OpenJDK's font rendering. So all you need is to swap OpenJDK to Sun JDK and fonts will look normal.

Here's how you do it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

After the installation finishes, if you wish to see if it was successful, you can run the following command:

```
java -version
```

It should return something like this:

```
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

To automatically set up the Java 7 environment variables, you can install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

[How to install Oracle JDK in Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

**UPD**

I forgot the main thing. In your .profile, enter this:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd_hrgb -Dswing.aatext=true -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true'
```

Alternatively, if you want to set font settings to specific applications, in this case, pycharm - instead of modifying .profile, you can edit pycharm/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions file and add this:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd_hrgb
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

Comment: I was having an issue with the `Ubuntu Mono` font being rendered strangely (especially the `i`s).  Following this answer made it better, but not perfect.  I also tried installing openjdk-8-jdk, and it gave the same result as the Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced OpenJDK with tuxJDK which works for me perfectly.

Here's a screenshot,

[image]

To install,

1. Download the JDK with `wget` or any httpclient.

   ```
   wget https://googledrive.com/host/0B68yuEpDuq6waUl5UjNTUWRlYTQ/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08.tar.xz
   ```
2. Extract downloaded JDK

   ```
   tar -xvf jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08.tar.xz
   ```
3. Move extracted files to `/usr/lib/jvm`

   ```
   sudo mv jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08 /usr/lib/jvm
   ```
4. set priorities to tuxjdk as 1

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/bin/java" 1

   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/bin/javac" 1
   ```
5. Correct permissions and ownership

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
   sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/
   ```
6. Now setup the defaults,

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```

   if the terminal shows **`"There is nothing to configure"`** quit this step. 
   it will prompt a selection window as shown below,

   ```
   There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

     Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
     0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
     1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
   * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/bin/java         1         manual mode

   Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
   ```

   enter the selection number adjacent to tuxjdk (here 2). 
   do the same for `javac` and select tuxjdk if it exists.

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config javac
   ```